# Join Spark dataframe with Cassandra table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to join a Spark dataframe with a table in Cassandra. The Spark dataframe (**table1**) has 2 million rows and the Cassandra table (**table2**) has more than 500 million rows.

I read the Cassandra table like this:

```
val table2 = sqlContext.read
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.options(Map("table" -> "table2", "keyspace" -> "test"))
.load
```

and then join like this:

```
val result = table1.join(table2, $"table1.id" === $"table2.id")
```

It seems that Spark fetches the whole table (all 500 million records) from Cassandra and then performs the join operation on Spark. Since this is too expensive for the network and disk resources, is there a way to fetch from Cassandra only the relevant records?

Comment: when you say "relevant" ? what do you mean by this? what ever join you performed based on id those records will come right? is there any filter needs to be applied to reduce number of records before joining them ?

Comment: @RamPrasadG I mean the records that also exist in table1. That's why I join the tables.

Comment: I see, as suggested by zero323 - pls have a look (  [joinWithCassandraTable](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable)  utilizes the java drive to execute a single query for every partition required by the source RDD so no un-needed data will be requested or serialized. This means a join between any RDD and a Cassandra Table can be performed without doing a full table scan. )